# How to call HTTP URL using wifi in J2ME code for BlackBerry 5.0 and above?

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me, wifi

I am calling a web service from BlackBerry using J2ME code.  When I try to open a connection using `HttpConnection`, it is checking only the GPRS connection.  Now, I want to check the Wi-Fi connection and call a webservice through Wi-Fi.

The following code is my connection section.  How to change the code for a Wi-Fi connection?

```
public boolean HttpUrl() 
{
    HttpConnection conn = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    try 
    {
        conn = (HttpConnection) new ConnectionFactory().getConnection(url).getConnection();
        if (conn != null) 
        {

            conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");


        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e2) 
        {
        }
    }

    //Only if exception occurs, we close the connection.
    //Otherwise the caller should close the connection himself.
    try 
    {
        conn.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this way:

```
HttpConnection conn = null;
String URL = "http://www.myServer.com/myContent;deviceside=true;interface=wifi";
conn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(URL);
```

[source](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Open_a_WiFi_HTTP_connection_509041_11.jsp)

Comment: As I understand it, the recommendation from BlackBerry is to code only ";interface=wifi".  I was told that the addition of ";deviceside=true" is not necessary and may confuse the connection choice logic.  That said, Nate's answer is my recommended approach too.

Answer (score 0):

### Making Connections

[Rafael's answer will certainly work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18161570/119114) if you know you'll **only** be using Wi-Fi.

However, if you only need to support BlackBerry OS 5.0 - 7.1, I would recommend that you do use the `ConnectionFactory`.  **Normally**, you will not limit your code to only using one *transport*.  [You'll normally support (almost) any transport the device has](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/CS_create_first_available_HTTP_connection_857706_11.jsp), but you may want to code your app to choose certain transports first.

For example,

```java
class ConnectionThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
        connFact.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[] { 
                TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI,
                TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B,
                TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS,
                TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR
        });
        ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
        connDesc = connFact.getConnection("http://www.google.com");
        if (connDesc != null)
        {
            HttpConnection httpConn;
            httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
            try
            {
                // TODO: set httpConn request method and properties here!
                final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Dialog.alert("Response code: " + 
                                Integer.toString(iResponseCode));
                    }
                });
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " 
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will choose the Wi-Fi transport if Wi-Fi is available, but use the GPRS connection if it isn't.  I think this is generally considered [best practice](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742?name=NetworkingTransportsII) for the 5.0+ devices.

### Request Properties

This code

```java
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

is not right.  `Content-Length` should be the size, in bytes, of your HTTP POST parameters.  [See an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175757/119114).

### Threading

Remember that making network connections is slow.  Do not block the user interface by running this code on the main/UI thread.  Put your code into a background thread to keep the UI responsive while you request remote content.